# How to integrate the drag and drop feature of the placeholder fields in Docusign Embedded in my web application using Java?

Tags: java, jsp, docusignapi

I am trying to integrate the drag and drop feature of the placeholder fields in Docusign Embedded in my web application. Instead of passing X and Y coordinates to set the place of the sign fields on the uploaded PDF, how do I integrate the drag and drop feature of the fields on the document through my web application using Java/JSP?

Comment: It is not clear what you want. What has JSP to do with PDF? What X and Y you mean? Passing from where to where?

Answer (score 0):

With drag/drop feature, you are adding a human in the flow to do the drag and drop of DS tabs on the envelope's documents. Instead if you are using API and if you own the document generation then you can explore the Auto-Place (Anchor Tagging) method or PDF Form Field Transformation if you have an AcroForm (aka fillable form PDF). [DS Developer Center](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/features/tabs) explains how to use these two methods. But if you have a requirement where human has to drag and drop instead of automatically adding DS Tabs via code then you can use [DS Sender View](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createSender) and this can be achieved with JAVA code as well. But this DS Sender View comes with a risk that if you open this page to someone then they can also see other envelopes which they are not supposed to see.